# Waiting time in FCFS is negative, why?

Tags: algorithm, operating-system, scheduling

Waiting time can never negative, but when I calculate the waiting time of FCFS, it is negative. What is the actual problem?

[image]

Comment: If P1 arrives at time t=9 and completes at time t=5, then it completes 4 seconds before it arrives.  This requires, indeed, a negative time.  The input data is faulty — GIGO (garbage in, garbage out).  Alternatively, that arrival time is t=4 (sloppy handwriting); then the step lasts 1 second.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

you have to correct your execution sequence of all the process, P4 has arrival time of 1 so it should execute first then compare the PID if there is clash between two or more processes.